# Couchbase Logging issue

Tags: log4net, couchbase, common.logging

I have got a strange issues with Couchbase once i update it to the latest version (through NuGet).

My MVC web app uses log4net loading it from unity container.

Suddenly Couchbase Cluster constuctor started to throw an exception saying:

```
Method not found: 
  'Common.Logging.ILog Common.Logging.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()'.
```

Stack trace:

```
   at Couchbase.Cluster..cctor()
```

Any idea? How could i solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried asking /reporting this issue to Couchbase forum? It could be a bug. see http://forums.couchbase.com

Comment: Hi, yes i tried. Here is my post in this forum https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-logging-issue/2589 and some workaround for the issue, but it took my so much time and i am not even sure this is correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problame.

Resolved it by adding dll compiled from current Couchbase.NetClient sources available on GitHub.

Issue was fixed by this commit https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/commit/a3f0544fd5e61e6b8c3cf0e829b8697e69021fda

Steps:

1. Download last version of sources https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client
2. Compile Couchbase project
3. Replace ..\packages\CouchbaseNetClient.2.0.1\lib\net45\Couchbase.NetClient.dll with compiled version in your solution

As far as CouchbaseNetClient 2.0.2 is released you can update it from NuGet.